# Python flask code - getting error on render_template when passing parameter

Tags: flask

I am trying to pass a parameter from the app to the template. Expecting the passed value to be read correctly but it is erroring out. But there is an error and need help to resolve the same.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

#print(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return(render_template('home.html'), name='name')
```

---

```
template - <h1> This is Home Page </h1>
<h2>{{ name }}</h2>
```

```
-----
Error - 
File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\urlShortner--60pnVFK\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 907, in app
raise err from None
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\urlShortner--60pnVFK\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 898, in run_command
app = info.load_app()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\urlShortner--60pnVFK\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 313, in load_app
app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\urlShortner--60pnVFK\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\MyPrograms\Python Virtual Environment created manually\urlShortner\app.py", line 11
    return(render_template('home.html'), name='name')
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your traceback isn't coming from that code.  There is no extra ```)``` at the end of that line.  Also, your parenthesis are wrong.  Should be ```return render_template('home.html',name='name')```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments you are returning a tuple and not what you want.

Try the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

#print(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', name='name')
```

The change is in the return line.

Note:

```
    return (render_template('home.html'), name='name')
```

This returns a tuple.  First value is the render_template('home.html')
result and the second value is `name='name'`  But this isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing extra parenthesis

```
return render_template('home.html', name='name')
```

You may need to add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```